# How to make a image without a background color in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I have tried on my website to make a background that links. Like this: `<a href="index.html"> <img src="background image"></a>`. And I want it to show up like this:

[image: good image]

But instead it shows up like this:

[image: bad image]

Comment: I can't see the difference. I only notice a different image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change that with css

```
<img src="background image" style="background-color: green;">
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "background-color: red"?